# Importing module from sub-directory works in Python 2, but not Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have directory with following structure:

```
> current_directory
    > submodule
        /__init__.py
        /some_module.py
    /main.py
```

In the `__init__.py` file the following statement is present:

```
from some_module import some_funciton
```

Whilst in the `main.py` the whole `submodule` is imported with: `import submodule`.

Now, this executed perfectly fine with Python 2, but the issue is that in Python 3 the `import` statement in `__init__.py` raises an `ImportError` exception: `No module named 'some_module'.

What is the difference between Python 2 and Python 3 when it comes to specifying the hierarchy of the imported files, and how would I go about adjusting the code to work with Python 3?

Comment: that should work. The only issue would be with `from x import y` statements. Are you sure you're not using `from` ?

Comment: Yes, I am. I simplified the problem too much for the presentation of the question. I'll edit it quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python 3 relative imports are supported only in the form `from . import submodule`.

You should either rewrite your `import` statement or make the import absolute by adding project directory to python path:

```
export PYTHONPATH=current_directory
python main.py
```

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up! Someone linked an answer to a different question that included this link: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/ . Which was also very helpful.